# Organizing common dependencies in two development branches

Tags: maven, version-control, code-organization

Given you have two branches of development which result in two different setups. Of course, the two branches share some common code. If you have changed some common functionality you have to copy-paste or merge the changes from one branch into another. Thats bad. Is there a better way to organize it?

Here are the ways I see.

**1) Create some 'core functionality' branch, place that shared module there and connect it to our build as a new artifact.**

**Pros**: we dont need to support two branches of the same code now, no more merges, all closely related classes are stored in one place.

**Cons**: common functionality is included in BOTH builds. 'Core' module's version change driven by Branch 1 in fact forces to change 'core' artifact version in Branch 2 build too, which implies re-testing. Otherwise we have to specify different versions of this 'core' artefact in each branch, which also bad.

**2) Same as previous point, but SEPARATE classes of the common module: place common classes into the 'core' artefact as in previous point, BUT leave branch-specific classes in the corresponding branches.**

**Pros**: now we dont have problem with versions and common functionality included in both builds.

**Cons**: its not a neat solution. In fact sometimes this means we have to place classes of the same type into different artifacts. for example, we have TextProcessor and NumberProcessor. Branch 1 a needs both, and Branch 2 needs only second one, so NumberProcessor goes to 'core' artifact alone, and TextProcessor stays in Branch 1. A litlle bit ugly solution: same functionality is spread between 3 branches.

**3) Place all common code into one 'core' branch as in p.2 and p.3, BUT do not separate branch-specific classes as in p.2 and do not build them in one artifact as in p.1, instead provide two ways for building 'core': a way for Branch 1 and a way for Branch 2.**

**Pros**: looks nice

**Cons**: again its not that easy: probably we have to filter classes by Maven somehow, what if there are dozens of differences, or may be create two copies of the common module inside 'core', so we benefit only because of using copy-paste instead of merge when changing same functionality.

May be some other options?

Comment: What does your branch specific mean? customer specific implementations ?

Comment: Yes, implementations, environment settings etc

Answer (score 1):

I would go a quiet simple way...create the following structure

```
+-- root (pom.xml)
     +--- core (pom.xml)
     +--- common (pom.xml)
     +--- customer-1 (pom.xml)
     +--- customer-2 (pom.xml)
```

With such a setup you don't need to having branches etc. for common/customer specific implementations. You have a (trunk/master) for all the modules and can make branches for feature oriented purposes. If you need customer specific put it into the appropriate module. If you find out that something customer-specific could be better be moved to common this is simple and can be done supported by your IDE simply refactoring the class into the appropriate module.

Comment: Thanks khmarbaise! Do you know if modern CI tools can support this structure? Indeed, looks like we need to make TWO builds from ONE branch and this builds should differ by the artifact they build and deploy (customer-1 for example) and they dont need to deploy the second one (customer-2).